# gnome shell desktop crashing in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell

Gnome shell desktop crashed on me in 17.10. This is what `journalctl` had to say.

```
Nov 02 22:44:04 HP-ProBook-450-G1 kernel: atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xa6 on isa0060/serio0).
Nov 02 22:44:04 HP-ProBook-450-G1 kernel: atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e026 <keycode>' to make it known.
Nov 02 22:45:02 HP-ProBook-450-G1 kernel: do_general_protection: 62 callbacks suppressed
Nov 02 22:45:02 HP-ProBook-450-G1 kernel: traps: gnome-shell[1638] general protection ip:7f56c0948de2 sp:7ffdaf215490 error:0 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.1[7f56c0913000+52000]
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gnome-terminal-[2466]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 update-notifier[2408]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 indicator-cpufr[1937]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 telepathy-indic[2052]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 systemd[1513]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 systemd[1513]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 systemd[1513]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1638]: (EE)
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1638]: Fatal server error:
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1638]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1638]: (EE)
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 polkitd(authority=local)[1005]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.75, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gnome-session[1529]: gnome-session-binary[1529]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gnome-session-binary[1529]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gnome-session-binary[1529]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1778]: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 bluetoothd[985]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 bluetoothd[985]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1638]: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Nov 02 22:45:50 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gsd-rfkill[1782]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gdm-password][1509]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user 
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gsd-color[1401]: failed to connect to profile: Failed to connect to missing profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_fc801af25bb2d5d61da96405d23ff139__1000
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 gsd-color[1401]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_AU_Optronics__1000
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 spacenavd[980]: Lost the X server!
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1669]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1669]:       after 44325 requests (44325 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 dbus[900]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=890 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.31" (uid=128 pid=1174 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")
Nov 02 22:45:51 HP-ProBook-450-G1 systemd-logind[890]: Removed session 2.
```

Comment: Does this happen all the time or did this only occurred once?

Comment: Since I upgraded to 17.10 it's been freezing pretty much daily, with the only solution being rebooting. Happened today as well. But now I've had the session crashing instead of freezing.

Comment: This could be a bug related to the wayland desktop server which replaces Xorg since 17.10. I can only suggest to report this bug in Launchpad with as much information as possible on how to reproduce it. In the meantime, you can use the Xorg server by choosing it on login. therefore, simply use the configuration menu in the bottom right corner when you enter your password.

Comment: Is there a difference between using Wayland and Xorg?

Comment: I would guess so, because of this line: `failed to read Wayland events` But I can't say more if you don't precise your problem.

Comment: The same is happening to me, 2 or 3 times a day. It writes in the syslog the following:
`kernel: [22818.213847] traps: gnome-shell[3063] general protection ip:7f58ba1eacdf sp:7fff1dad5578 error:0 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.5400.1[7f58ba1b5000+52000]`
But I'm not using Wayland, but still Xorg.
The screen freezes, but I could enter in a virtual console (ctrl+shift+f3). When I came back to the original console, the screen was still frozen, but I could move the mouse.

Comment: I think [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1725932) is related.